# Running XAMPP on Mac with other user not working

Tags: wordpress, macos, apache, permissions, xampp

I'm currently having a problem with XAMPP and WordPress on my Mac. I've downloaded the latest XAMPP version and installed it on my Mac.

After moving WordPress into the `htdocs` folder, I've got an error in the Dashboard because of missing write permissions.

After searching for some minutes, I've tried to give everyone access to the htdocs folder via the Finder. But that don't helped. So I've tried this here:

https://www.zigpress.com/2018/03/19/resolving-permissions-issues-in-xampp-on-mac-high-sierra/

So I've entered my local Mac user name (`johnnymarten`, found out via whoami) and the group `staff`. The problem is, that the Apache Server don't starts anymore now and I'm getting this error message here:

> INFO: Starting "apache" 
>   ERROR: Failed to start "apache": cannot start
>   service: AH00543: httpd: bad user name johnnymarten

I'm coming from Windows and I don't get this done. I'm at lease done with this. Do you have any idea what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Xampp runs as root. Reset file permissions to get it to start.

1) reset directory: `sudo chown -R root:admin /Applications/XAMPP`

2) on my Xampp 2 directories are different:

`sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/logs`

`sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp`

3) Make a new directory for WordPress and let everyone use it.

`mkdir new_dir`

`chmod 777 new_dir`

4) Add directory to httpd.conf

```
<Directory "/new_dir">
Options ExecCGI FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
</Directory>
```

Load WP in /new_dir

Restart Apache.